# How to split delimited text in a column, fetch respective ID from another table and store in a new column

Tags: sql-server, split, calculated-columns, csv

I have a column i.e. `p_author` in sql server table named as `sub_aminer_paper` containing values of single or multiple authors having data type `text` separated by semi-colons i.e. `;`
Now I have to assign the respective id's to this column values i.e. `p_author` where id's for these authors are stored in another table named `sub_aminer_author` in the column `aid`.
The view of both tables are attached as images.
Table `sub_aminer_author`

[image: sub_aminer_author]

Table `sub_aminer_paper`

[image: sub_aminer_paper]

I have highlighted `aid` and `name` columns in `sub_aminer_author` table and `p_author` column in `sub_aminer_paper` table.

Now I have to add a new column named `p_authors_id` in `sub_aminer_paper` table and fill it with respective `aid` from `sub_aminer_author` table.

I am attaching the sample data in `csv` format for both table (only concerned columns data)

Here are the links to csv files

[sub_aminer_paper](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ihKgOLimL0cEtyYVR0WExBbFk)

[sub_aminer_author](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ihKgOLimL0MUhHZFlpLThTZzA/view?usp=sharing)

And for the table creation, here is the code --
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sub_aminer_paper](
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [p_author] [varchar](max) NULL)`

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sub_aminer_author](
    [aid] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](max) NULL)`

Please help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you mention above the #sub_aminer_author contains first three character as number so this query will work according to requiment

```
select left(name,3) as aid ,
       substring( [name], 4 ,len(name) )as name 
from #sub_aminer_author
```

More over for  sub_aminer_paper you have given wrong CSV file kindly check it..as i can see the example it contains 5 character as numeric so this query wil work accordingly..

select left(name,5) as aid ,
           substring( [name], 6 ,len(name) )as name 
    from #sub_aminer_paper

Please find the updates query for #sub_aminer_paper

```
              SELECT left (name,(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',name)-1) ) as pid,
Substring(name, Patindex('%[^0-9]%', [name]), Len(name)) as p_author
FROM #sub_aminer_paper
```

Comment: --I have given in csv only (aid, name) for sub_aminer_author table and (pid, p_author) for sub_aminer_paper table

Comment: pl find the CSV  file which u  attached ,both the files containing only sub_aminer_author

Comment: @Raja--now please have a look--I have sorted out the correct file issue (csv)